# Chrome graphical glitches Checker-imaging error

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome

Hello my about:gpu page in chrome shows the following error:
[image]

This started appearing after I messed around with tomcat and mysql. There are also graphical glitches in Chrome. I don't know what exactly lead to this.

How to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: This is a new feature that is being added to the latest versions of Chrome. It is disabled by default because it is still in testing only. There is basically no chance it is causing the glitches you are reporting. If anything, enabling it may give you some glitches.

Comment: @trikly Actually I face those glitches when I am using TeamViewer and the remote partner opens chrome on my laptop. So I assumed this was the cause. But I did not yet check whether turning this flag on resolved the issue.

Comment: Sorry. Missed this before. I know I've run into such problems using Remote Desktop. I would guess that hardware acceleration might be at fault.  You may want to mess with settings related to that. There can be an issue where the driver for the shared screen and the one for the main screen interfere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to add this flag in /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop file

```
--enable-features="CheckerImaging"
```